# Basic Python repetition exercise

Tags: python

I was trying to learn Python when I came upon this question. I am not asking for you to answer the question for me, I just need some help. **Note: I am only allowed to use loops and if statements etc. Nothing ahead.** I don't understand where I can use loops to create this program or the formulas needed.

Your parents need to buy a new vehicle and they are trying to
decide whether to purchase a hybrid or not. Hybrid vehicles
produce less CO2 emissions and have better fuel efficiency
compared to their non-hybrid counterpart. However, hybrid
vehicles also cost a lot more money than their non-hybrid version.
Help your parents make a decision as to which type of vehicle to
buy (strictly in terms of the financial cost and not taking into account the environmental
benefits). The typical family drives 20,000 kms each year and gas currently costs $1.30/litre.

Allow the user to enter the cost of the hybrid and non-hybrid vehicle along with the
combined fuel efficiency of those vehicles. Also, allow the user to enter the average amount
of kilometers they drive each year (note: the average is 20000 km/year). Then output how
many years of ownership it will take for the two cars to equal in cost. Assume that the price
of gas stays the same at $1.30/litre.

Obviously, the cost of gas will increase each year (this is called inflation). Incorporate into your calculation the idea that gas
prices will rise by 3% each year (i.e. annual inflation rate is 3%).

**This is what I have so far:**

```
count=0
total=0
gas=1.30
avgkm=20000

normalcost=input("Please enter the cost of the non-hybrid vehicle: ")
hybridcost=input("Please enter the cost of the hybrid vehicle: ")
fueleff=input("Please enter the combined fuel effiency of both vehicles: ")
```

Comment: what are the formulae you'd use to calculate inflation?

Comment: What is your question/what part don't you understand/where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't understand where I can use loops or the fuel effiency part.

Comment: you'll need to use loops to calculate the costs for each year

Comment: I understand that but what are the formulas I would need to use? I don't understand how to incorporate fuel effiency with the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer without providing too much code (after all, it's your homework, not mine).

First: Your question is about how many years the cost of a car (including fuel cost) will be equal (or similar) to the cost of the other car. So, you need three things: a year counter and two accrued costs:

```
i = 0              # The year counter
cost_a = price_a   # The accrued cost of car A: It starts with the cost of the car
cost_b = price_b   # The accrued cost of car B: It starts with the cost of the car
```

Then, you need to add the cost every year, so you need a loop that does three things: increment the year count, and add the costs to each car on every iteration. So, you need to ask yourself these questions:

1. How much do you need to increment the costs for each car?
2. What is your 'stop' criteria? In other words: When will you stop iterating?

For the increment, on each iteration you will need to do something like this:

```
i = i + 1    # Add a year
cost_a = cost_a + year_costs_a    # The increment of costs for car A during the year
cost_b = cost_b + year_costs_b    # The increment of costs for car B during the year
```

Finally: Inflation. Remember that inflation 'changes' the price every year, so:

```
price = price * (1 + inflation_rate)
```

Of course, you need to initialize the price with the appropriate value for this to make any sense.

---

All things said, to solve this problem (or any other programming problem), you need to 'split-and-divide' it in little tasks (or steps), and then try to put it all together.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I greatly appreciate it. Also, I needed help with " year_costs_a" and "year_costs_a". I understand that I need the total cost of each vehicle each year in those variables, but I don't understand how to incorporate fuel effiency and such. Again, Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @BalkarnGill The problem gives you the answer to that: the cost for car A is the number of gallons it 'burns' every year, multiplied by the cost of the gallon (same for car B)

Comment: Okay thank you!
"cost_a = cost_a + year_costs_a" Why are you adding the cost of the car on each iteration?

Comment: because you will need to track *when* the cost of a car is more of equal to the cost of the other car (I would use a financial present value criteria, but that's just me). You will need the accrued costs to define the stop criteria (if you don't keep track of costs, how will you stop the loop?)

Comment: Alright and last question, for the fuel effiency, wont the 2 formulas be different? Considering one is more fuel efficient than the other? If so, what will my 2 formulas be?

Comment: @BalkarnGill Of course you will need different formulas for every car, since they have different efficiencies. If car A gives 10 Km / lt and car B gives 20 Km / lt, you can expect that the year cost of car B is far less than the year cost of car A. Assuming both cars travel 20,000 Km / year and a $1.3 per lt: `year_cost_a = (20000 / 10) * 1.3` and `year_cost_b = (20000 / 20) * 1.3`

Answer (score 0):

You have two vehicles, costing `hybrid_cost` and `standard_cost`. Each year, each car drives a certain distance. The total cost for the year is `km_driven * liters_per_km * dollars_per_liter`. `dollars_per_liter` increases each year by 3%, meaning that for each year *i*, `price = base_price * (1 + 0.03 * i)`.

The hybrid starts out with a cost of `hybrid_cost - standard_cost` right at the beginning, and adds to that, while the standard starts at zero. What do you think the endpoint will be?

One key part of programming is *functions*, where small generic calculations can be defined to run with certain input, and *loops*, which perform specified operations a certain number of times, then stop when one or more criteria are met. Hopefully this will be enough to get you started...

Comment: Thanks! But why are you subtracting the standard cost from hybrid cost?
And would the 2 formulas to calculate yearly cost be the same or different? Considering one is a standard vehicle and the other one is a hybrid.

Comment: @BalkarnGill this is the initial price difference - the hybrid costs more than the standard, so the hybrid's owners have already spent that much more money. The whole point of the program is to keep track of the accumulating amount each owner spends, until they both have spent the same amount. That's how you figure out how many years of ownership it will take for the two cars to equal in cost. After that point, all things being equal, the hybrid owner will be spending less than the standard owner because their fuel efficiency is higher. You need to figure out how long it takes to get there.