# A little assistance with my program

Tags: python

I needed some help with this program. I already tried something but it doesn't seem to work. When I click run, nothing happens. I think there may be something wrong with my loop but I am not too sure. Also I do not know how to add the inflation in. **Any help is appreciated!**

**Additional info:**
Your parents need to buy a new vehicle and they are trying to
decide whether to purchase a hybrid or not. Hybrid vehicles
produce less CO2 emissions and have better fuel efficiency
compared to their non-hybrid counterpart. However, hybrid
vehicles also cost a lot more money than their non-hybrid version.
Help your parents make a decision as to which type of vehicle to
buy (strictly in terms of the financial cost and not taking into account the environmental
benefits). The typical family drives 20,000 kms each year and gas currently costs $1.30/litre.

**Question:**
Allow the user to enter the cost of the hybrid and non-hybrid vehicle along with the
combined fuel efficiency of those vehicles. Also, allow the user to enter the average
amount of kilometers they drive each year (note: the average is 20000 km/year). Then o
output how many years of ownership it will take for the two cars to equal in cost.
Assume that the price of gas stays the same at $1.30/litre.

Obviously, the cost of gas will increase each year (this is called inflation).
Incorporate into your calculation the idea that gas prices will rise by 3% each year
(i.e. annual inflation rate is 3%).

**This is what I have so far:**

```
i=0 # The year counter
gas=1.30
avgkm=20000
inflation=1.03
standard_cost=0
hybrid_cost=0

standard_cost=input("Enter the price of the non-hybrid car: ")
hybrid_cost=input("Enter the price of the hybrid car: ")
fueleff1=input("Enter litres/100km for the standard car: ")
fueleff2=input("Enter litres/100km for the hybrid car: ")

standardyear=avgkm/100 * fueleff1 * gas + standard_cost
hybridyear=avgkm/100 * fueleff2 * gas + hybrid_cost

while standard_cost != hybrid_cost:
    i += 1    # Add a year
    standard_cost += standardyear    
    hybrid_cost += hybridyear
    if hybrid_cost==standard_cost:
        break

print "It will take",i,"years. "
```

Comment: Works on my machine (rather, it at least produces output). Are you using an IDE? Have you tried running it straight from the command line?

Comment: I am using WingIDE.
I have tried running it straight from the command line and it still won't work. There is no error or anything, it just stops and does not display anything. Other code works though. Its something wrong with this code. Maybe an infinite loop? I'm not sure.

Comment: one of your classmates just asked for help with this question a few hours ago.

Comment: To be entirely clear: are you starting the program and it immediately does not display anything? Or, are you starting the program, entering values for the four user input prompts, and then it does not display anything?

Comment: After I enter the four values, it says "Executing command. Please wait for result". Then nothing pops up.

Comment: try reading through [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748382/basic-python-repetition-exercise) for help. You sort of have the right idea, but you're missing a few things

Comment: It seem that you can convert the input string to int.

Comment: no, you want to use `float(input("Give me numberz!!11!! "))` because you'll be doing division later

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues:

1) Your loop will only exit if standard_cost is exactly equal to hybrid_cost
   you might want to try breaking out of your loop when hybrid_cost <= standard_cost

2) the lines

```
if hybrid_cost==standard_cost:
    break
```

in your while loop are redundant with the conditional statement in the while

Comment: The question is asking me to output how many years of ownership it will take for the two cars to equal in cost. So wouldn't the it still be hybrid_cost==standard_cost?
Also what do you mean with 2)

Comment: Also even if I use hybrid_cost <= standard_cost, it still will not work.

Comment: The problem is, it will probably not be an exact amount of years. Say at year 5 the hybrid costs 5000 and the standard 4900. At year 6 it could be hybrid 5500 and standard 6000. So it will never be the exact same number.

Comment: But can't it be like 1.2 years? With decimals and such

Comment: in 2) I mean that you don't need those lines at all. The while loop will exit as soon as hybrid_cost == standard cost.

Comment: Oh okay I see. I took those lines out but still the program doesn't work. Do you have any idea where I screwed up? I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the loop, still don't know where though.

Comment: The actual answer might very well be 1.2 years, but you are only ever incrementing the year counter by a whole year at a time so you will never test that condition and the loop will never exit.

Comment: Okay I understand but did you find the error in my loop? As to why it doesn't display anything.

Comment: You only display the answer after the loop exits. If the loop never exits, you will never see an answer.  Try this: add line line inside your loop that prints out the values of i, hybrid_cost, and standard_cost. That way you'll be able to see whats happening to those values as the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will stop only if `standard_cost` equals `hybrid_cost` exactly. You should stop the loop if `hybrid_cost <= standard_cost`.